# Generalization of trace norm identity

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a $2\times 2$ complex matrix $M$, the sum of its singular values (i.e. the trace norm) can be written as: $$\mathrm{Tr}\,|M|=\sqrt{\mathrm{Tr}(M^\dagger M)+2|\mathrm{Det}(M)|}$$
Is anyone aware of a generalization of this formula for higher dimensional square matrices?

Comment: I found one for 3x3 but it's the most ugly thing I've ever seen. It depends only on $\mathrm{Tr}(M^\dagger M)$, $\mathrm{Tr}(M^\dagger MM^\dagger M)$ and $\mathrm{Det}(M^\dagger M)$, but it has a huge number of terms, with cubic roots, it's too nasty to be useful... : (